# URL launcher not working with flutter web in some android devices

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am tryng to open a file with url launcher (From this https://pub.dev/packages/url launcher) with flutter web in a private server like http://192.168.0.1/file.apk and in some android devices this thing just doesn't work. I have tried opening this file via Android 9+ and ios devices and it works but in some other devices the page seems to be opened and it closes without warning.

May i need to add another stuff to make it work?. I think i'm just missing something. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] I was missing an implementation dependency 
url_launcher_web: ^0.1.0